# Amazon RDS master password reset fails

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, rds

I have a mysql database in an amazon rds instance. After yesterday's backup, I am unable to login to the server and I am unable to change the master password.

When I try to change it, this message appears in db logs :

```
Your password reset workflow failed due to this error: unable to: set password for ?@'%' = PASSWORD(?), caused: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Can't find any matching row in the user table
```

I tried rebooting machine, nothing changed.

As far as I understand from the error message, our master user does not exist. (Since there is quiestion mark right before '@' sign).And AWS does not let us change master username.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException`+`?@'%' = PASSWORD(?)`.... that tells you that some parameterized query get screwed up... How are you trying to connect to the rds instance..did you try all of this: `You can use the AWS Management Console, the Amazon RDS Command Line Interface, or simple API calls.`

Comment: I tried connecting both from my ec2 instance and externally. Both fails. I will try the CLI tools

Comment: What method are you using to change the password? Are you using a MySQL client, or are you using an AWS tool? I believe you can change the master password directly through the RDS web console.

Comment: I am using RDS web console since that is the only way I can interact with the db. Error logs belong to the RDS web console.

Comment: Once again, the error message that I pasted in the post, belongs to the RDS console. When I try to change the master password through RDS Console then the error above pops up.

Comment: You can change the DB instance password by using the Amazon RDS console, the AWS CLI command modify-db-instance, or by using the ModifyDBInstance action.

Comment: But did you try from the AWS CLI?

Comment: I am trying to install it, currently when I say "sudo pip install aws-shell", it gives me error saying distribution not found.

Comment: From was cli: `aws rds modify-db-instance --db-instance-identifier yourdatabasename --master-user-password abcd1234`

Comment: It says I have to specify region. You know which parameter I should specify for region?

Comment: Finally, i was able to execute the command. However it still results in same error

Comment: The most likely explanation is that you somehow deleted your own master user account.  Did you create any other user accounts before you lost access?

Comment: I did but none of them has appropriate privileges to do what I need. In the RDS Management Console, I still see the master username which makes me think that user itself should still be there